# What are the drawbacks to compiling C++ projects with /clr:safe to enable unit testing?

Tags: .net, c++, unit-testing, nunit

I would like to introduce unit testing to our C++ product and wanted to investigate the pros and cons of trying to use the CLR-based unit tests.  I've read that if you compile with the /clr:safe option, you can call your existing C++ code.

I'm strictly a .NET developer, so I'm at a loss for how this would affect our codebase.  What should I know about before I try to introduce this to the C++ team?

Comment: There are many other C++ unittesting frameworks available you may want to explore, as /clr:safe is probably unrealistic for a C++ codebase.
I personally have good experiences with Boost.Test, but your mileage may vary :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to work, at all. The C++ code **will not compile** under /clr:safe; pretty much every line will give an error. /clr:safe gets you a language that basically shares no datatypes with C++.

Answer (score 1):

/clr:safe will allow you to use "C++.NET", which is not likely the same thing that a "C++" team works with.  Unless they're willing to recode to use ".NET C++" (which has the ^ operator for 'new objects on the heap' for starters) their stuff won't work.